# Gradle jettyRun set webappsourcedirectory with DropWizard

Tags: java, gradle, jetty, dropwizard

So I'm developing a DropWizard application and all of the tutorials point towards compiling and running `java -jar` to start the web server. However while I'm doing local development this is a pretty slow work flow. Having used Jetty before I know it will autoreload and run in a daemon mode.

We're using Gradle and I found [this](https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.JettyRun.html) which works to start Jetty. The first problem I encountered is this:

```
Directory '/src/main/webapp' specified for property 'webAppSourceDirectory' does not exist.
```

I found I way around this by adding

```
jettyRun.webAppSourceDirectory = file("src/main/java")
```

to the `build.gradle` file but of course this just lists files in that directory. Is there a directory I can point jetty to for this to work?

Or is there another way I can get DropWizard to auto reload resources and recompile?

Also Is there a way to get DropWizard to run in the background?

Answer (score 0):

Dropwizard doesn't run on Jetty. It manages Jetty, as well as other tools. So manipulating jetty is not a solution for what you want to accomplish.

> Or is there another way I can get DropWizard to auto reload resources
>   and recompile?

No AFAIK.

> Also Is there a way to get DropWizard to run in the background?

Also no AFAIK. You should be able to fix that with some bash tricks.
Or maybe [this](https://github.com/robertcboll/x-dropwizard-daemon) might be of some help, but I don't think it will recompile and reload resources.

Dropwizard is a fairly lightweight application. In my development environment it takes about 3-5 seconds to build and start a dropwizard service; that is by using Intellij, not gradle (or maven).